# PHP and HTML submit form does not work

Tags: php, html

I have a simple form for users to sign up to e-mail updates. The HTML code on the page is as follows:

```
<form id='send.php' method='post'>
    <input type="email" name="emailaddress" placeholder="Your e-mail address"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The contents of `send.php` is as follows:

```
<?php

if($_POST["submit"]) {
    $recipient="email@email.com";
    $subject="Email address for updates";
    $sender=$_POST["emailaddress"];
    $senderEmail=$_POST["emailaddress"];
    $message=$_POST["emailaddress"];

    $mailBody="$message";

    mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody,"From: $sender");
}

?>
```

If I test this, it does not work. The mailbox where these emails should be sent works fine and there are no emails in the spam folder, so I don't know what is wrong.

I am indeed a beginner with HTML and PHP.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sometimes mail() function do not work , check with your hosting website. Or if you want to be sure , echo those variable out and see if you have the correct value

Comment: @PoomrokcThe3years what you are saying is very true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not look much on your php but I sported some mistakes on the html code so 
First change this

```
<form id='send.php' method='post'>
    <input type="email" name="emailaddress" placeholder="Your e-mail address"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

 To


<form id ="myform" action="send.php" method="post">
    <input type="email" name="emailaddress" placeholder="Your e-mail address"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: GENIUS!! how did I miss that . I award you "Eagle eye" Badge Xb

Comment: Am so glad that you appreciated but all of us junior and seniors we can be caught in such a situation where by you can forget simple things like that .

Comment: @humphrey Thank you so much! It was just that id/action mistake you picked up. It woks perfectly now, thank you!